# Sort a list according to another list in common lisp

Tags: sorting, lisp, common-lisp

How would you sort `list` according to the order defined in another list `sorter`:

```
list = ( (:value "A" :index 0) (:value "B" :index 1) (:value "C" :index 2) )
sorter = (1 2 0)
```

Resulting in:

```
list* = ( (:value "B" :index 1) (:value "C" :index 2) (:value "A" :index 0) )
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why this should be considered off-topic. Many SO questions that are routinely considered legitimate include no attempted solutions. In this case the question and the desired behavior is specified at least as precisely as many other questions that have been considered legal. The downvotes are appropriate, though, for the lack of effort.  Does sound like homework, too, as Diego Sevilla suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
(defun my-sort (lst idx)
  (labels 
      ((getall (i) (remove-if-not (lambda (e) (=  i (getf e :index))) lst)))
    (loop for i in idx append (getall i))))
```

then

```
(my-sort '((:value "A" :index 0) (:value "B" :index 1) (:value "C" :index 2)) '(1 2 0))
=> ((:VALUE "B" :INDEX 1) (:VALUE "C" :INDEX 2) (:VALUE "A" :INDEX 0))
```

Comment: Alternatively: `(defun my_sort (lst idx) (sort lst #'(lambda (a b) (< (position (getf a :index) idx) (position (getf b :index) idx)))))`, or a little more flexible `(defun my_sort (lst idx &optional (srt #'<)) (sort lst #'(lambda (a b) (funcall srt (position (getf a :index) idx) (position (getf b :index) idx)))))`

Comment: This one is not particularly good in terms of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a homework. I'll give you some indications on how *I* would do it at first sight. Doesn't mean it's the best solution, but certainly can point you to a way of solving it.

Get the `sorter` list, and build a hash table that, for each number in the list, stores its position in the list (for instance, it will hold `( (1 -> 0) (2 -> 1) (0 -> 3) )` with the list you show.)

Next, use any sort function that is appropriate in the CL library specifying a `:key`and a compare function accordingly. That is, the key function should access to the index field in each element, the compare function should compare the values in the hash for each of the index field element.